# @Url.Action("Login", "HECAccount") not working in cshtml (layout)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm creating vertical menu for my asp.net mvc 4 web application.

so I referred [this Link](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/1324/jQuery-and-CSS3-Vertical-Menu-effect) to integrate to my matter .

so I edited my _HECLayout.cshtml (that contains in “~/Views/Shared/”) file Like this

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>


<script type="text/javascript" src='~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js'/></script>   
 <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="~/Content/css.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 



    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('ul.formxd li a').click(
                function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
                    e.stopPropagation; // stop the click from bubbling
                    e.stopPropagation; // stop the click from bubbling
                    $(this).closest('ul').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
                });
        });
    </script>   



        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - Higher Education Council</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

        <div id="header">
             <div id="top-area">
                <div id="logo-area">
                   <img src="~/Images/hec-logo.png" />
                </div>



    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">

                   <div class="float-right">
                     <section id="text-view" style="display: inline; width: 100%; text-align: right;" >
                       <p><i>Higher Education Institutes </i></p>
                    </section>
                    </div>
                 </div>
        </header> 
          @RenderSection("featured", required: false)

        <div id="menu_area">
            <div class="hec_admin_menu" >
               <ul class="formxd">


        <li class="welcome"><a class="welcome"><i class="icon-fa-university"></i>Welcome HEC</a></li>
        <li ><a class="dashboard" href="#"><i class="icon-dashboard"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
        <li ><a class="reports" href="#"><i class="icon-file"></i>Reports</a></li>
        <li><a class="administrator" href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>Administrator</a></li>
        <li><a class="search" href="#"><i class="icon-search"></i>Search</a></li>
        <li><a class="logout" href="@Url.Action("Login", "HECAccount")"><i class="icon-signout"></i>Logout</a></li>

    </ul>

            </div>


            <div class="hec_admin_body">

            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
           </div>
        </div> 

        <footer>

        </footer>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

It's giving smooth view like the demo which I mentioned [HERE](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/1324/jQuery-and-CSS3-Vertical-Menu-effect) , but logout url action not working properly.And all the urls not working properly ,

Any suggestion to overcome with his probblem

```
<li><a class="logout" href="@Url.Action("Login", "HECAccount")"><i class="icon-signout"></i>Logout</a></li>
```

Comment: Remove `<script type="text/javascript" src='~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js'/></script>` from the `<head>`. Your already including it with `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`. What is `logout` redirecting to the `Login` method in `HECAccountController`? And all the other links have `href="#"` so what do you expect them to do?

Comment: Have you created the Login action in HECAccount controller.what exactly you are getting an error ?

Comment: what you mean by not working?

Comment: @StephenMuecke you're very correct I Removeed <script type="text/javascript" src='~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js'/></scrip !!! thanks lot , I'm new to javascript with asp.net , anyway thanks all, its working now

Comment: Why are you calling `e.preventDefault()` on all `<a>` tags. This prevents the redirect!

Comment: I'm still trying to become familiar with these techies , shall I remove that one ? will it give any other effect other than you mentioned ?

Comment: If your what you link to redirect to `/HECAccount/Login` then you should not be calling `e.preventDefault();` or `e.stopPropagation;` since this stops the click event firing the redirect. And there is not much point changing the `class` since since the link immediately redirects and you no longer on this page (so whats the point). Not really sure what your trying to do here, especially with the `href="#"` which means its a link that doesn't lead anywhere on its own.

Comment: I'm keeping some of links as href="#" , because in future I'm willing to add more redirections , such as href="@Url.Action("Registeration", "HEC")" ,
 if I remove e.preventDefault(); will it effect to them also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got same error when I trying to insert jquery reference like above , links doesn't working

So I referred [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534938/jquery-ui-not-working-in-mvc-4-after-scripts-render)

That's an approach to give jquery reference to HTML Page , but in CSHTML when you insert `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` you don't need add one by one references like you done here ,

So remove `<script type="text/javascript" src='~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js'/></script>`

keep  `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` under the code

If your project doesn't have the "**jquery-2.0.0.min.js**"  file , manually insert into  "**~/Script**" Folder

Comment: with the help of StephenMuecke I overcome with my problem before  but Thanks kelum for Additional Knowledge